# How to adjust listView's height to a fragment under it

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I have an `Activity` with an `ExpandableListView` and hidden `Fragment` under it. When you click on a ListView's child element, fragment becomes visible and appears from the bottom with a smooth animation. The problem is that when fragment appears it overlaps a part of the list, so I can't see elements at the bottom. In order to fix that I assume I could dinamically adjust listView's height as fragment pops up, but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Here's an example of what it looks like before showing the fragment:

[image]

And that's what happens after it (and I can't scroll down anymore):

[image]

Here's the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:
    android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:childDivider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:groupIndicator="@null" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/musicBarContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution! The trick is that you just need to align the container to the parent bottom, then set your listView's height to `match_parent` and put it above the container. Since listView takes all the possible height but still have to be above the conatiner it will automatically shrink as fragment appears in the container.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_background"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/musicBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/musicBarContainer"
        android:childDivider="@drawable/list_divider"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" />
</RelativeLayout>
```